# Real Analysis problems

Tags: real-analysis

Let A be a set of real numbers and let B = {-x: x an element to A}. Find a relation between MaxA and MinB and between minA and MaxB.

I went through this and I found that the set B essentially maps out A but flips the negatives with the positives and vice versa. Thus both have neither a minimum nor a maximum. Therefore, MaxA = infinity and MinA = negative infinity.

Is this correct? Sorry for the lack of proper math symbols, I'm still trying to understand this code

Comment: supposedly its the Real Numbers

Comment: @user3491648 The OP said $A$ is an arbitrary set of real numbers.  I don't see anything wrong with assuming that.

Comment: @AlexanderKing Are you sure the problem doesn't use $\sup{A}$ instead of $\max{A}$?  $A$ might not have a maximum.  Take $\Bbb Q \cap (1,2)$.  This set of real numbers has a supremum, but not a maximum.

Comment: How about doing the calculation in case $A = \{-7,9\}$ for starters?

Comment: everything listed above is all thats mentioned. nothing else extra is given.

Comment: You have to say something about the cardinaliy of A and I feel you must assume A is not finite and not closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your intuistion is correct given a set $A$ and define $-A$ as you defined $B$ then we have the following properties :
$$\max(-A)=-\min(A)\ \ \ \ \min(-A)=-\max(A) $$
when $\min(A)$ and $\max(A)$ are well defined

Answer (score 0):

I guess the exercise meant $A \subset \Bbb R$. It is not correct, just take, say, $A = [0,1]$. Let's write $B = -A$, for clear reasons. We have $\min A = 0$, $\max A = 1$. But $-A = [-1,0]$ and so $\min -A = -1$ and $\max -A = 0$. If you draw it on the real line it will be easier to think. Makes you think that: $$\min-A = -\max A, \qquad \max-A = -\min A.$$

I'll prove the first one, you do the other one.

Take $x \in A$. So $x \leq \max A \implies -x \geq -\max A$. Since this is true for all $-x \in -A$, we get that $\min -A \geq -\max A$.

On the other hand take $x \in -A$. So $x \geq \min -A \implies -x \leq -\min -A$. Since $-x \in A$ is arbitrary, we get that $\max A \leq -\min -A$, hence $-\max A \geq \min-A$.

So we conclude: $$\begin{cases} \min -A &\geq -\max A \\ -\max A &\geq \min-A \end{cases} \implies -\max A = \min-A.$$